# How to Loop through linq query results and add result to Html table header in listview

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, loops

Hi I just want to start by saying I'm very new to LINQ and .NET. I am trying to grab a set of data using a linq query and populate the data as HTML table headers inside my listview. I can't hard code the headers since the headers are different for each organization I run the query on.

The following is an example of a query where im getting all the profile names for an organization and I would like to have each profile as a table header in my listview:

```
var organizationProfiles =
                (from profile in orgWorkProfiles.WorkProfiles
                 join org in orgWorkProfiles.Organizations on new { profile.OrganizationId } equals new { OrganizationId = org.Id }

                 where org.Name == ddlOrg1.SelectedItem.ToString()
                 select profile.Name);
```

and this is what my List view looks like in the presentation page:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ltv_main" runat="server">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table id="reportTable" width="100%">                        
                <thead class="headRowDetails" >                                                
                    <th class="headRowDetails">Profile1</th>
                    <th class="headRowDetails">Profile2</th>
                    <th class="headRowDetails">Profile3</th>
                    <th class="headRowDetails">Profile4</th>  
                    <th class="headRowDetails">Profile5</th>                     
                </thead>                                                      
                <tbody>                        
                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
                </tbody>
            </table>                
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
                <tr class="normRowDetails">                        
                    <td>Eval some data here</td>
                    <td>Eval some data here</td>
                    <td>Eval some data here</td>
                    <td>Eval some data here</td>
                    <td>Eval some data here</td>                 
                </tr>
        </ItemTemplate></Listview>
```

As you guys can see I'm currently hard coding the table headers in the  but this is not what is required and I would like to be able to make the headers dynamic. Can someone please help me figure this issue out? If it is not possible to dynamically create headers in list view is there an alternative solution to this? Your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me... if I understand correctly the Linq query you describe returns the Profile names... I miss the query returning the value that you want to put into header ?

Comment: Hi Yahia. The profile names are the values that I want to use as headers. The issue is I don't know how to assign the profile names as table header values inside the list view. I hope that clears the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can data bind the layout template of list view, which I have done but thats probably slightly more complex if you are relatively new.

How about separating the header from the list view that you are using. Use the list view for binding the items only and have a literal control write the header separately. You can use css to position them accordingly.

Comment: Hi Coder net. Thanks for taking the time to help me out. Will it be possible if you can give an example of both solutions that you suggested? Thanks.

Comment: check this link out. You should specify your header in the user control. http://weblogs.asp.net/davidfowler/archive/2008/12/14/dynamic-listview-layouttemplate.aspx